# How do I add a UIButton or UISwitch in tableView:viewForFooterInSection

Tags: objective-c, iphone, cocoa-touch, uitableview, uikit

I'm trying to understand how to add a label with a UISwitch or other controller to a footer (or header) in a sectioned tableView. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Okay, after searching and working at it I've done the following:

```
// Need to refactor so that the label is Public Sharing and Priviate Sharing and the actions work for each switch
- (UIView *) tableView: (UITableView *) tableView
viewForFooterInSection: (NSInteger) section
{
  if (section == 0 || section == 1) {
    CGRect screenRect = [[UIScreen mainScreen] applicationFrame];
    UIView* footerView = [[[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, screenRect.size.width, 44.0)] autorelease];
    footerView.autoresizesSubviews = YES;
    footerView.autoresizingMask = UIViewAutoresizingFlexibleWidth;
    footerView.userInteractionEnabled = YES;

    footerView.hidden = NO;
    footerView.multipleTouchEnabled = NO;
    footerView.opaque = NO;
    footerView.contentMode = UIViewContentModeScaleToFill;

    // Add the label
    UILabel*    footerLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(150.0, -5.0, 120.0, 45.0)];
    footerLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    footerLabel.opaque = NO;
    footerLabel.text = @"Sharing";
    footerLabel.textColor = [UIColor tableHeaderAndFooterColor];
    footerLabel.highlightedTextColor = [UIColor tableHeaderAndFooterColor];
    footerLabel.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:17];
    footerLabel.shadowColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
    footerLabel.shadowOffset = CGSizeMake(0.0, 1.0);
    [footerView addSubview: footerLabel];

    [footerLabel release];  

    // Add the switch
    UISwitch* footerSwitch = [[UISwitch alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(215.0, 5, 80.0, 45.0)];
    [footerView addSubview: footerSwitch];

    // Return the footerView
    return footerView;
  }
  else return nil;
}
// Need to call to pad the footer height otherwise the footer collapses
- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForFooterInSection:(NSInteger)section {
  switch (section) {
    case 0:
    case 1:
      return 40.0;
    default:
      return 0.0;
  }
}
```

I hope this is correct and if this helps anyone else please vote this up.  Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

i think you need to autorelease the uiview-